# Taqueria La Michoacana -- what's the significance?

Tags: adjetivos, nombres-propios

What does this construction mean and what are it's limits? Why isn't it Taqueria de la Michoacana? Is this a common way of naming things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less as MikeWats mentioned, stores are often named by store type (*zapatería*, *bar*, *cafetería*, *taquería*, etc) and then given a juxtaposed name (that is, placed without a preposition).  It's common anywhere not just in Mexico but all over the Spanish-speaking world, although less so with newer more commercial/(inter)national places that go with a single brand name.

Answer (score 2):

It is just the name of the taquería

- The United Fruit Company is a company name.
- La Michoacana in this case is the name too. Since Spanish uses more articles than English, stores names have one most of the times.

Answer (score 2):

In "La Michoacana" the article "La" is telling you that the place is bound to "Michoacan" state, being "Michoacana" treated like you would treat a nationality.

It's like "The American Shop", you're saying that the shop is bound to America or has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The full name is "La Michoacana"

For instance  , could be :

Ferretería **Don Pepe**
Taqueria **Los Hermanos**
Neveria **La Michoacana**  -->  Famous in Mexico

In México  is a common way for naming stores , in this case it´s named for the State of Michoacan.

Comment: +1 I've seen "Neveria/Paleteria La Michoacana" places in multiple Mexican states...

Answer (score 0):

It could be but it is just written another way.

Simply put its a simple adjective followed by a proper noun.

You'd say the same in English as:

- Record Store "The Beetles"

Or something similar along those lines.